# pgjdbc-ng Ill-formed region:

Tags: postgresql, pg-jdbc

Currently i'm trying to make a module which will listen to any changes via trigger on Postgres. I'm using pgjdbc-ng ver 0.8.2 ,download the JAR from maven repo central and add it as project reference.

Following is the code that i used :

```
public class ListenNotify
{
// Create the queue that will be shared by the producer and consumer
private BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);

    // Database connection
    PGConnection connection;

    public ListenNotify()
    {
        // Get database info from environment variables
        /*
        String DBHost = System.getenv("DBHost"); 
        String DBName = System.getenv("DBName");
        String DBUserName = System.getenv("DBUserName");
        String DBPassword = System.getenv("DBPassword");
        */
        String DBHost = "127.0.0.1"; 
        String DBName = "dbname";
        String DBUserName = "postgres";
        String DBPassword = "postgres";
        // Create the listener callback
        PGNotificationListener listener = new PGNotificationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void notification(int processId, String channelName, String payload)
            {
            // Add event and payload to the queue
            queue.add("/channels/" + channelName + " " + payload);
            }
        };

        try
        {
            // Create a data source for logging into the db
            PGDataSource dataSource = new PGDataSource();
            dataSource.setHost(DBHost);
            dataSource.setPort(5432);
            dataSource.setDatabaseName(DBName);
            dataSource.setUser(DBUserName);
            dataSource.setPassword(DBPassword);

            // Log into the db
            connection = (PGConnection) dataSource.getConnection();

            // add the callback listener created earlier to the connection
            connection.addNotificationListener(listener);

            // Tell Postgres to send NOTIFY q_event to our connection and listener
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("LISTEN q_event");
            statement.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
    * @return shared queue
    */
    public BlockingQueue getQueue()
    {
        return queue;
    }

    /**
    *
    * main entry point
    *
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    // Create a new listener
        ListenNotify ln = new ListenNotify();

        // Get the shared queue
        BlockingQueue queue = ln.getQueue();

        // Loop forever pulling messages off the queue
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // queue blocks until something is placed on it
                String msg = queue.take().toString();

                // Do something with the event
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon running, i got exception :

Ill-formed region: Indonesia [at index 0]

I have read the official git, saying that it should be fixed within some release number.

How do i apply those fix ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know its a little bit late ;)

I had the same problem and also read that the problem was solved. But it does not seem that way. 
Anyway the problem is this when creating the postgres database, LC_COLLATE is probably set to Indonesian_Indonesia.1252. When trying to establish a connection this value is compared with the java locales. In the Java Locales class, the value is probably in your language so the entry can not be found. However, to solve the problem you can set the default value of the Java locales to English. This is certainly not the best way to solve the problem, but it works. For security, I would put back after the connection is established

you can set the default value as follows:

`Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH)`